# Возможно ли передать и установить cookies с одного домена на другой при перенаправлении в Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, cookie

Есть html-страница на localhost, я в нее подставляю cookie и произвожу перенаправление на страницу другого домена, однако cookie по пути теряется, как её сохранить для другого домена и возможно ли это?

Код которым подставляют куку:

```
 document.cookie = 'key=value';
```

Comment: куки одного домена не доступны для другого, иначе бы любой сайт мог своровать ваши пароли от вк)

Comment: Невозможно в целях безопасности, ищите другой способ передачи данных

Answer (score 0):

Возможно. Для этого вам нужно выполнить следующие шаги:

1. Получить cookie с сайта А.
2. Преобразовать полученный cookie (его данные) таким образом, чтобы его можно было передать в URL.
3. Собственно добавляем преобразованный cookie к URL на который будут происходить перенаправление на сайт Б.
4. На сайте Б, считываем переданный cookie из URL.
5. Производим обратное преобразование.
6. Устанавливаем cookie для сайта Б (не забыв указать правильный domain для сайта Б, вместо А).

Comment: К исходникам сайта Б доступа нет. Обычно подставляю туда cookie с помощью Chrome dev tools вручную, однако захотел автоматизировать этот процесс с помощью какого-то нибудь скрипта.

Comment: @coolsv тогда вам стоит более подробно описать это действие в самом вопросе, ибо в текущем виде пользовательский случай таких шагов не ясен.

Answer (score 0):

По умолчанию cookies не могут быть переданы с одного домена на другой из-за ограничений безопасности браузера. Однако, есть несколько способов, как вы можете передать cookies с одного домена на другой:

1. Используйте специально назначенный параметр SameSite, чтобы разрешить передачу cookies с одного домена на другой. Чтобы это сделать, нужно будет выставить параметр SameSite в значение None, а параметр Secure - в значение true. Например:

---

```
document.cookie = "key=value; SameSite=None; Secure"
```

- Используйте механизм аутентификации через прокси-сервер. В этом случае вы можете установить cookies на одном домене, а затем отправить запрос через прокси-сервер, который будет содержать эти cookies. Прокси-сервер будет перенаправлять запрос на другой домен с переданными cookies.
- Используйте технику "CORS-headers". Это позволит вам установить cookies на одном домене, а затем отправить запрос с использованием JavaScript на другой домен с заголовками HTTP, указывающими на то, что запрос разрешен. Чтобы это сделать, вам нужно будет установить следующие заголовки:
- Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * - разрешает все домены отправлять
  запросы.
- Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true - разрешает передачу
  cookies.

Чтобы отправить запрос с использованием JavaScript, вы можете использовать один из следующих методов:

- XMLHttpRequest
- fetch API

Пример отправки запроса с использованием fetch API:

```
fetch('https://other-domain.com/path', {
  credentials: 'include'
});
```

Обратите внимание, что эти техники могут не сработать в старых браузерах.

Comment: Добрый день. Сделал всё как вы сказали, но это не работает https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75189230/chrome-dont-send-cookie-with-allow-cors